# White Space Issue using percentage

Tags: html, css

I am newbie to CSS while designing one page 
CSS

```css
  
     body {width:100%;height:920px;margin:0;list-style:none;padding:0;}
    .side{background-color:#9966FF; width:20%;height:920px;float:left;}
    .main{background-color:#CCFFFF; width:80%;height:920px;}
```

```html
    <body>
    <div class="side">Its side bar</div>
    <div class="main">ites center bar</div>
    </body>
```

But its giving me some white space after the main class so what my understanding is if I am giving body as 100% it will divide that space in 20% and 80% in .side and .main class please correct me?

Comment: show us a jsfiddle. I dont know why you have 100% on the body

Comment: thanks @connexo I learned it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the `float: left` on `div.side` has the effect of making 100% of the body's width available for `div.main`. This is just how floating works. So just remove the `width: 80%` and instead make it `margin-left: 20%;` and you're done.

To better understand what's going on, check the following fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ex6w7tnz/1/

(Which has the width on div.main removed but not added a margin-left.)

So the floating `div.side` does not affect the width of `div.main`, but only the position of the content inside it which is right of `div.side`. This is called floating :) So when you assign a width of 80% to div.main, the "white-space" which you assumed is right of it is just the remaining 20% width of the body's 100% which div.main does not use.

Comment: Nice explanation. beat me to it. :)

Comment: @Mytri You might want to click the checkmark left of my answer showing that this answer solved your issue.

Comment: By default, a floating element takes only as much width as is required for its content´, so in this case you need to assign a width to it. By default an empty floating element has a width and height of zero. I recmommend you install Firebug Addon in your Firefox. This helps you tremendously to analyse what's going on! Alternatively, if you use Chrome, you can also use its built-in development tools which you can access via F12.

Answer (score 0):

Add `float:left` on `.main` class

```
body {width:100%;height:920px;margin:0;list-style:none;padding:0;}
.side{background-color:#9966FF; width:20%;height:920px;float:left;}
.main{background-color:#CCFFFF; width:80%;height:920px;float:left;}
```

Comment: So if I will use float on .side it will float elements and if .side width is 20% and main width is 80% from where white space come?

Comment: @Mytri Please try to understand my answer above. It's all explained there in detail.

Comment: you need to add float:left on both classes, then it will not come any white space.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you give `float:left`  to `.side` but not to `.main` div. So, from `.main` 80%, 20% will inside the side div.

Like if i give 30% to `.main` div then it will show only 10%. other 10% will be cliped.

```css
body {width:100%;height:920px;margin:0;list-style:none;padding:0;}
    .side{background-color:#9966FF; width:20%;height:920px;float:left;}
    .main{background-color:#CCFFFF; width:30%;height:920px;}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="side">Its side bar</div>
    <div class="main">ites center bar</div>
    </body>
```

Same way if i set 20% then it didn't show anything and text goes below. Check

```css
body {width:100%;height:920px;margin:0;list-style:none;padding:0;}
    .side{background-color:#9966FF; width:20%;height:920px;float:left;}
    .main{background-color:#CCFFFF; width:20%;height:920px;}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="side">Its side bar</div>
    <div class="main">ites center bar</div>
    </body>
```

To to fill whole body you need to give `float:left` to `.main` div. So, it display side by side.

```css
body {width:100%;height:920px;margin:0;list-style:none;padding:0;}
    .side{background-color:#9966FF; width:20%;height:920px;float:left;}
    .main{background-color:#CCFFFF; width:80%;height:920px; float:left;}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="side">Its side bar</div>
    <div class="main">ites center bar</div>
    </body>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Though this is a long answer, it doesn't help the man to understand what's going on. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

That's what you are trying to do, you were on the correct track. The are multiple ways of activating the same result with HTML and CSS.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  height:920px
}
.parent > div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
}

.side {
  width: 20%;
  background-color:#9966FF;
}

.main {
  background-color:#CCFFFF;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="side">text</div>
    <div class="main">text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Float clearing issue.
Here is an alternative: https://fiddle.jshell.net/ts2trhpf/
You can use `display: inline-block`